# IEnumerable collection item null check

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words

I have a BookmarkCollection class which is an IEnumerable inheritance used in Aspose words document generator and I have to check every hard-coded bookmarks inside of a docx file to be fed from this method. I need to check if it is empty or not to fill in the bookmark. Considering a lot of bookmarks in the collection, I am looking for a better way to do that.

```
private void FillBookmarks(long AppID, BookmarkCollection bs)
{
    if (bs["Bookmark1"] != null)
    { 
        //fetch data fill it in the docx file for Bookmark1 
    }
    if (bs["Bookmark2"] != null)
    {
        //fetch data fill it in the docx file for Bookmark2 
    }
    if (bs["Bookmark3"] != null)
    {
        //fetch data fill it in the docx file for Bookmark3
    }
    //if statements goes on and on
}
```

Considering about lots of possible if statement additions to come, how can I improve the

The BookmarkCollection is this:

```
public class BookmarkCollection : IEnumerable 
{ 
    public int Count { get; } 
    public Bookmark this[int index] { get; } 
    public Bookmark this[string bookmarkName] { get; } 
    public void Clear(); 
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator(); 
    public void Remove(Bookmark bookmark); 
    public void Remove(string bookmarkName); 
    public void RemoveAt(int index); 
}
```

Giving more info about the bookmarks and what to do about them : 
Bookmarks1,2,3 are different kind of data to be retrieved such as price, customerAddress, product name, vendor and etc. 
When the collection has the string i.e. "Vendor", the `do something` method will retrieve the data from database.

Comment: Is bookmark collection a dictionary?

Comment: You `IEnumerable` is very abstract, is it a collection of `string`?

Comment: Either way, there is possibly a way to make it more 'elegant' yes, but that depends on what the `do something else` is.

Comment: The [BookmarkCollection](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/BookmarkCollection+Class) from Aspose documentation. They don't use generics at all :O

Comment: you could use a `foreach` loop

Comment: struggling a lot about how to use code in comments.

Comment: @ganilyalcin the answer is don't  if you need to give more information, then edit into your question

Comment: @DeeMac `do something else` is a method for each of the bookmarks to be filled. Each of them are seperate data.

Comment: @ganilyalcin Could you give us the type of the `BookmarkCollection` enumerated items. For example with, `foreach (object item in bookmarkCollection) { Console.WriteLine(item.GetType()); }`.

Comment: @FelipeOriani thanks for the edit aboout the collection.

Comment: I am unable to understand your issue. It would be better if you can share some samples with us to give us a better understanding regarding what document you have and what output you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

How about my snippet. Create a method like below in your `BookMarkCollection` class

```
public void DoActionOnFindBookMark(string elementName, Action action)
{
   if (true) // here you have to check for match element
   {
      action();
   }
}
```

So that you can write your `if` statement like below

```
BookMarkCollection collection = new BookMarkCollection();
collection.DoActionOnFindBookMark("BookMark1", () => { Console.WriteLine("found bookmark1"); });
collection.DoActionOnFindBookMark("BookMark2", () => { Console.WriteLine("found bookmark2"); });
```

Comment: In this case I will need to create methods as much as the if statements.

Comment: You could write the methods somewhere else in the class, taking the bookmark name as an argument, and then simply pass those methods directly into this DoAction method. (No need for "() => " syntax)

Answer (score 0):

you do have a count and an int indexer, so iterating over all bookmarks with a for loop should not be a problem.
and the class is an IEnumerable, so you can just say `foreach (var b in collection)…`. by definition all of them will be !=null.